# BigQuery cli bq how to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE script

Tags: sql, bash, google-bigquery, bq

I would like to use two SQL scripts to create and update a table in BigQuery using `bq query` command.
Here are the two scripts :

1- Creating the table

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.newtable (
        id STRING, ''' ||
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(
                segment || 
                " INT64 " ORDER BY segment
        ) FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM dataset.source
        )
    ) || 
    ''')''';
```

2- updating the table

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    '''INSERT dataset.newtable (
        SELECT id, ''' ||
        ( SELECT STRING_AGG("COUNTIF(
            segment = '" ||
            segment ||
        "') AS " ||
        segment ORDER BY segment
    ) FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM dataset.source
    ) ) || 
    ''' FROM dataset.source GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1
)''';
```

When using these two scripts as queries with the `bq query` command, I have got an error :

```
Syntax error: Expected keyword IMMEDIATE but got to end of the script at [1:8]
```

Is there any other way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: All the script is stored in a shell variable.
When calling the `bq query` command, I use the specific variable (which contains `||` as text)

Comment: Here is what i use : 

`createTableQuery="
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.newtable 
(id STRING, ''' || (SELECT STRING_AGG( segment || \" INT64 \" 
ORDER BY segment) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT segment FROM dataset.source) ) || ''')''';
"`

And when calling the `bq` cli : 

`bq query "$createTableQuery"`

Here is the encountered error : 

`Encountered " <ID> "EXECUTE "" at line 2, column 1.`

Comment: Tried to remove them but got an error (even in BigQuery's interface).
In [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting?hl=fr#execute_immediate), They replaced simple quotes with double quotes. Tried that but still got the same error with `bq query` command :/

Comment: I have also tried this : 
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataset.newtable2 (id STRING) ";`
Unfortunately, same issue.
I am beginning to think that using this type of queries (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`) cannot be done using the `bq` cli :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default query dialect in the `bq` command-line tool is legacy SQL. You need to switch to the standard SQL dialect to be able to run scripts:

1. `--use_legacy_sql=false` or `--nouse_legacy_sql` flag to your command-line statement.
2. prefix your sql with `#standardSQL`

[image]

You can also set standard SQL as your default. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#setting_standard_sql_as_the_default_for_the_command-line_tool).

Comment: Thank you Polley for your help! It did work perfectly.
I tried to use a variable to store the script but got issue with unclosed strings.
I prefer using your method (file) since `bq query` read directly from the stdout and makes  code more clean.

Comment: Glad I could help :)